# Bing Maps Streetside availability

Tags: bing-maps, bing, bing-api

How many cities is Bing Maps Streetside available in? I can only find resources from 2014, is there any current info on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is not documented number of cities in which streetside is available. Note that it is available outside of many cities as well. The easiest way to see what coverage is available for streetside is to zoom the map out and press the streetside button. A blue overlay with the coverage will appear. Currently it is available in the US, UK, France, and Spain.

[image]